# how to update internet explorer 11 to the version 11.1155.15063.0

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, windows-update, internet-explorer-11

I have searched in many forums and in windows update, but I would like to install the manual update Internet Explorer 11 **11.1155.15063.0** in windows update does not appear

My operating system is Windows 10

[image]

I need to test particularly that only works in this particular version of IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to install the manual update Internet Explorer 11
>   11.1155.15063.0 in Windows Update does not appear.

Internet Explorer 11 updates on Windows 10, are connected to the monthly, Windows 10 cumulative updates.  **Internet Explorer 11.1155.15063.0** is only available if you are running **Windows 10 build 15063.1155**.

If you have KB4284830 installed you should uninstall it, and verify you are running 15063.1155 instead of 15063.1182 after you uninstall it.  Of course, if the issue, only appears in 15063.1155, you should perhaps NOT attempt to fix an issue that only appears in last month's cumulative update for an outdated version of Windows 10.

Windows 10 Version 1703 build 15063.1155 is [KB4284874](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4284874).  Internet Explorer 11.1155.15063.0 **does not exist** on any other version of Windows except that build.

[KB4230450](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4230450/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer) is not applicable to Windows 10.