# How to determine the exact version of Internet Explorer on a(n up-to-date) Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

If I follow the steps outlined [in this MS support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/which-version-of-internet-explorer-am-i-using-86e0ab5e-c60b-bc44-655d-cb4c69f5a3c2) (Tools / About Internet Explorer), I only get the version information of Windows, not Internet Explorer.

[image]

UPDATE: Some more explanation how I ran into this & why I considered this worth posting.

First off: *please* don't try to convert me to other browsers / fresh versions, I'm already using them. It's not me, it's this weird software vendor we have, who lives in the '90s, and states silly software requirements in user manuals. Such as:

> Microsoft Internet Explorer version 11 from Update Version 11.0.45
> (Security Update for Internet Explorer 4034733)

Said vendor's software did not work out of the box, so I had to do some sanity checks and as part of that, I had to check browser compatibility.

Since I am not an expert on the history of how Microsoft changed the versioning policy of IE, I simply could not put a less than / more than relation between the version strings "11.0.45" stated in the manual and "21H1" stated in the IE About window.

So I had to do a little research. Websearch and SO.com did not turn up answers that were on-topic *and* terse, the first relevant hit was the MS material I referenced in the answer.

Comment: [I explained IE versioning on Windows 10 5 years ago.](https://superuser.com/questions/1336004/how-to-update-internet-explorer-11-to-the-version-11-1155-15063-0/1336022#1336022)

Comment: **I didn’t downvote your question.** It’s considered to be extremely rude to excuse users of downvoting your contributions. My answer from 5 years absolutely explains what’s going on, the major build number of IE, will match the major build number of Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, apologies for that and also thanks for not voting down. Still, my opinion is, that your answer for 4 years ago does not explain why the IE About menu shows me a Win10 version window. Also somewhat strange that your answer is dated 2018-07-02, while the Win10+IE behaviour my question is about originates in Win10 version 1809 released in 2018-11-13.

Comment: Yes; While the answer talks about a previous update, it explains what's happening with the IE versioning on Windows 10.  Your question is about 21H1. not 1809, no idea why you brought it up. Internet Explorer's build is still connected to the Windows build number i.e. 19043 in the case of 20H2.  On 21H1 that version would be `11.x.19043.0` not that it matters IE11 is identical on all supported version of Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Microsoft changed the behaviour of the IE11 About window in Windows 10 version 1809. Now, instead of showing the "real" IE About window, it just runs winver.exe, which is for showing OS version ([see this source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/information-about-ie-version#changes-to-the-about-internet-explorer-dialog-in-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-10-version-1809-and-later)).

Luckily, the same MS web article also mentions a workaround. The following registry key contains the exact IE version:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\svcVersion**

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\svcVersion`  will entirely be based on whatever version of Windows 10 you installed.  Enablement Packages for 20H1 (2004), 20H2, and 21H1 won't update the key.  1809 was the feature update that could be installed with an enablement package.